# How to integrate Luis into bot builder

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to use the `FormBuilder` in combination with my intents as I created them in **Luis**. I just can't find the documentation to do this.

I would like to do the following things:

1. A user would enter a phrase which is interpreted with **Luis**.
2. If not all entities are given in the phrase the form builder will fill in the gaps.

How do I do this? Is there a tutorial? I see people talking about `LuisDialogs`, but I just don't know where to start.

Comment: I found this is a good article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/an-interactive-bot-application-with-luis-using-microsoft-bot/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**In a nutshell :**

- First you have to create an account on luis.ai.
- Then you need to follow this documentation: http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html (It starts with classical Dialogs but ends with Luis integration.)

**Here are some steps** (but you should definitely follow the guide I linked):

Basically it is a class which inherits `LuisDialog<object>` and you have to put an attribute on top of it with your Luis id and secret

```
[LuisModel("c413b2ef-382c-45bd-8ff0-f76d60e2a821", "6d0966209c6e4f6b835ce34492f3e6d9")]
[Serializable]
public class SimpleAlarmDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{ [...]
```

Then you add method to your class and decorate them with the `LuisIntent(...)` attribute.

```
 [LuisIntent("builtin.intent.alarm.turn_off_alarm")]
 public async Task TurnOffAlarm(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
 { [...]
```

Inside the method, you can search if an entity was found using a code like this :

```
EntityRecommendation title;
if (result.TryFindEntity(Entity_Alarm_Title, out title))
{
    what = title.Entity;
}
else
{
    what = DefaultAlarmWhat;
}
```

Finally, to start the dialog, you have to call this Inside your controller:

```
public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {
        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {
            // return our reply to the user
            return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            return HandleSystemMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I've looked at the PizzaBot example and I managed to get my code working :-)

Comment: Perfect! can you mark the answer as useful so other people having the same question can rely on it? :)

Comment: If the entity is NOT provided, how can i prompt the user to provide just the entity information in second step ? Do i need to update the Luis model to be able to take just 1 word as the entity and link it with the intent ?